# What is the `:'<,'>` in the command line?

Tags: command-line, visual-mode

When I press `:` from visual mode, the command line is pre-populated with `:'<,'>`. It seems to affect how my substitutions work.

What do the characters mean and why are they inserted?

How does `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g` differ from `:s/foo/bar/g`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitute command can accept a range prefix. Without it, like:

```
:s/foo/bar/g
```

Will just substitute on the current (cursor) line.

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

Will substitute on the whole file.

```
:5,10s/foo/bar/g
```

Will substitute on lines 5 through 10, inclusive.

When you visually highlight some text, there are two marks that are automatically updated, mark `<` denoting the beginning of the visual area and `>` the end.  When you have something visually selected and press `:` Vim assumes you want to do whatever command you're about to type on the visual area, so it pre-populates the command line.

See `:help cmdline-ranges` for more information on ranges, and `:help mark-motions` for more information on the various marks that can be used.